# HTML5/Javascript to only play one audio sample at a time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have the following code which allows me to press a button and play and audio sample. It works in that respect, however, the notes overlap when I press a different button, but I would like the pressing of a button to stop the playing of the previous note(s) and play only the sound associated with the most recent button push. How can I achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<script>

var e = new Audio('/Users/username/Downloads/e-note.mp3');
var d = new Audio('/Users/username/Downloads/d-note.mp3');
var g = new Audio('/Users/username/Downloads/g-note.mp3');

function play (note){

note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();

}

</script>

<button onclick="play(e)"> Click Me </button>
<button onclick="play(d)"> Click Me </button>
<button onclick="play(g)"> Click Me </button>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great question because I myself is looking for a better way to do this. What I did so far for my previous stuff is to do a for loop of each audio elements and pause it. Then I load the audio file and play it for the particular one that I want.

Comment: @RuChernChong Why would you want a better way?  That's the proper way.

Comment: I never thought that was clean enough.

Comment: @RuChernChong What's not clean about it?  Another way would be to re-use the Audio object, changing its `src`, but then you wouldn't be pre-buffering the audio data... this may or may not be an issue depending on your specific application.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, I changed my method to re-use that particular audio element to load and play the audio track.

Comment: @RuChernChong - So how is this done? sorry! I'm fairly new to javascript

Comment: Do a for loop and stop all audio from playing then play the one that you want.

Comment: You should read a [tutorial on using arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I know what arrays are, but I'm struggling to understand how they could be used for this?

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<audio id="audio1">
    <source src="alarm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Javascript

```
var myAudio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
myAudio1.play();
```

Comment: You did not stop or pause all the other audio first

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up doing which works. I have no idea if there is a more efficient way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<script>

var e = new Audio('/Downloads/e-note.mp3');

var b = new Audio('/Downloads/b-note.mp3');
var g = new Audio('/Downloads/g-note.mp3');
var d = new Audio('/Downloads/d-note.mp3');
var a = new Audio('/Downloads/a-note.mp3');
var el = new Audio('/Downloads/elow-note.mp3');

    function play (note){

if (note==e) { 
b.pause(); g.pause(); d.pause(); a.pause(); el.pause();
note.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();
} 


if (note==b) {
e.pause();g.pause();d.pause();a.pause();el.pause();
note.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
note.pause();
note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();
} 

if (note==g) {
e.pause(); d.pause();b.pause();a.pause();el.pause();
note.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
note.pause();
note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();
} 

if (note==d) {
e.pause(); g.pause();b.pause();a.pause();el.pause();
note.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
note.pause();
note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();
} 

if (note==a) {
e.pause(); d.pause();b.pause();g.pause();el.pause();
note.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
note.pause();
note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();
} 

if (note==el) {
e.pause(); d.pause();b.pause();g.pause();a.pause();
note.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
note.pause();
note.pause();
note.currentTime = 0;
note.play();
} 

}


</script>

<button onclick="play(e)"> E </button>
<button onclick="play(b)"> B </button>
<button onclick="play(g)"> G </button>
<button onclick="play(d)"> D </button>
<button onclick="play(a)"> A </button>
<button onclick="play(el)"> E </button>


</html>
```